# reduce condition checking in jsx of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
{!loading && (ad.status !== 'active' && ad.status !== 'paid') && <div>
  display something base on not active and not paid
</div>}

{!loading && ad.status === 'paid' && <div>display content base on paid</div>}

{!loading && ad.status === 'active' && <div>display content base on active</div>}
```

I have above 3 condition and have 3 different block of html, above code just work but I felt the `!loading` declaration is too repeatable, how to improve code above?

`!loading` is a must because I don't want to show anything before the API fetch is pending.

Comment: Use a function instead, then use one `!loading` condition, and return whatever you need to when one of the other conditions is met.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function like this:

```
function getContent(status) {
  switch (status) {
    case 'paid':
      return (<div>display content base on paid</div>);

    case 'active':
      return (<div>display content base on active</div>);

    default:
      return (<div>display something base on not active and not paid</div>);
  }
}
```

... and then change your code block into:

```
{!loading && getContent(ad.status)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting into it's own component/function and then do this:

```
if (loading) {
    return null;
}

{(ad.status !== 'active' && ad.status !== 'paid') && <div>
  display something base on not active and not paid
</div>}

{ad.status === 'paid' && <div>display content base on paid</div>}

{ad.status === 'active' && <div>display content base on active</div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like [`recompose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) for that:

```
const BaseComponent = ()=>(
  <div>this is your most common case (blue sky scenario)</div>
);

// add special cases as branches
const FinalComponent = compose(
    branch(({loading}) => loading, renderNothing)),
    branch(({ad}) => ad.paid, renderComponent(PaidContent))),
    branch(({ad}) => !ad.active, renderComponent(InactiveContent))),
)(BaseComponent)
```

I might have mixed up which case is your normal case and which cases are the exceptions. But this gives you an idea of how it works.

In our project our Base components never include loading and edge cases. This makes the normal case code a lot easier to read.

Note: The order of the `branch` calls is important.